# Is there a way to change the internal radix of Java code?

Tags: java, integer, environment, radix

If I want to write a program that deals almost exclusively with, say, base 8 math, is there a way to change the source code or JVM to perform all calculations with this radix without having to explicitly change it on every integer reference?

For example, instead of...

```
private static final int RADIX = 8;

// ... then, elsewhere ...

System.out.println(Integer.toString(3 + 7, RADIX));
```

... I could just do ...

```
System.out.println(3 + 7);
```

... and have it print the same result of `12`?  Is there some environment variable or in-code setting I can apply?  Or is this simply not possible?

This may seem arcane or a "why in the world would you want to do this" scenario, but if you can imagine having to perform a large number of non-trivial calculations under a different base, then you can see how it would become extremely tedious extremely fast to have to keep manually converting numbers to the appropriate radix.

Comment: There's a difference between *calculating* in a different radix vs. *printing* in a different radix. Which do you want?

Comment: In point of fact, there's no such thing as calculating in a different radix.  The result is always the same.  The only time you care is when you're reading input and printing output.

Comment: @Jeff Well, you can't really calculate in a different radix. It's built into the hardware. So it'll always be in radix 2.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I was mixing up how I thought of the number to how it was represented in the system. :)  Regardless, the question holds.  Thanks for pointing out the flawed logic, Louis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no feature like that.

A number is a number no matter what base you're talking about, the radix only comes in when converting to/from strings. If you have to do this all of the time, then create some utility methods that do the work, and always call them. Alternatively, write your own Integer-like class that handles the fromString/toString bit.

```
public final class OctalInteger extends Number implements Comparable<OctalInteger> {
    // Basically a copy of Integer.java, but changes the methods dealing with Strings

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

Also, why would you want that? Imagine how many pieces of code you would break that run in the same JVM - no one coding libraries would expect the default radix to suddenly change.

Your use of a constant is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change default radix. But you can easily write your own `print` and `println` procedures which would print integers in octal base.